# Why does Spring Sleuth TraceId get carried over MQ when 'spanId' is added as a message header to the JMS message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have been agonizing over trying to get the Spring Cloud Sleuth traceId to carry over MQ for quite some time. As I understand based on various articles this is currently unsupported.
Yet when I attempted to add "spanId" as a header property on a JMS message I observed that on the MQ listener side the traceId was carried over automatically and I cannot explain why.

Can someone please help me understand why the below code works ?

Note: spring-cloud-starter-sleuth version = 3.0.0, Spring Boot version = 2.4.3

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class MQMessagePublisher {
       private final JMSTemplate;
       private final Tracer tracer;
       
       public void publishDummyMessage(){
          TextMessage textMessage = new JMSTextMessage("some data");
          Span span = tracer.currentSpan();
          message.setStringProperty("spanId", span.context().spanId());
          jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("SOME_Q_NAME", message);
       }
    }       
 
  public class MQListener {
     @JmsListener(id="listener", destination = "SOME_Q_NAME", concurrency = "2-4")
     public void listen(Message message) throws JMSException {
       
        log.info("Span Id: {}", message.getStringProperty("spanId"));
     }
  }
```

Apologies for any syntax errors. I did not copy this code from my editor - just wrote it freehand just now but you should be able to replicate my observations with this.

The thing I cant understand is why does this work ? The log statement in the listener clearly carries across the same traceId without any additional work.

UPDATE :

Earlier the question was written incorrectly - its actually the traceId that gets carried over when the 'spanId' is added to the jms message.
I have updated the question above with the correct terms.

Comment: because of this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/e4ff2dd051edc4b485bab51d6dd55c002bbf555b/spring-cloud-sleuth-brave/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/config/TracingJmsListenerEndpointRegistry.java#L50

Comment: Based on this comment in the class: "Internal class for Sleuth, do not use. Its API can change at anytime", it looks like this is just current internal behaviour that cannot be relied on in future releases , am I right ?

Comment: You shouldn't extend this but it works fine

Comment: It works, but will this behaviour be preserved in future releases of spring cloud sleuth?

Comment: There will be no new feature releases of Sleuth (3.1.x) is the last one. We are not planning to remove anything there.